# Write a 64-bit program in C

Tags: c, 64-bit

This might be a very stupid question:

- How do I write a program especially for 64-bit architecture.

We are working on a Solaris system.

Is there any difference in the code itself for 32-bit and 64-bit?
Or is it more a question of header-files?

Can anybody give me a simple hello-username example for 64-bit?

Comment: What kind of program are you writing?

Comment: the key difference is the size (in bytes) (and therefore max values) for numeric variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a 64-bit program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

This program is also safe as a 32-bit program, and also safe as a 16-bit program.  There is not necessarily any difference in a program depending on the number of bits it is compiled for.

Here's an alternative program:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

This is going to produce different answers for 32-bit systems and 64-bit Unix systems, but 16-bit systems and 64-bit Windows systems will produce the same answer as 32-bit systems.

Note that both these programs have identical source code, and use the same headers, regardless of whether they're compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit (or 16-bit, or 8-bit per [Grzegorz Szpetkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586873/grzegorz-szpetkowski)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958828/write-a-64-bit-program-in-c/26958888#comment42456480_26958888)).  One of the programs has different behaviour depending on the platform (compiler) and whether it is compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit mode; the other produces the same output regardless.  Clearly, the value of `LONG_MAX` derived from the header may be different depending on the compilation mode.

Comment: The main difference between 32bit and 64bit compilers that you will run into is the size of pointers.  32bit ints, chars etc... will be the same number of bytes.  But pointers will always be 32bit in size on a 32bit system, and 64bit in size on a 64bit system.  I wrote a simple program which shows the sizeof() each type of variable, and they were all the same except the pointer.  The pointer points to memory of course, and so it must be able to contain any address 32 or 64 bit can handle.  A normal int is four bytes in size, while you can create a 64bit int variable with "long long int".

Answer (score 3):

It is compiler specific.

If you are using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (on [Sparc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/SPARC-Options.html#SPARC-Options) or on [x86](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options)), I guess that you use

```
gcc -m32 -Wall -g hello.c -o hello-32
```

and

```
gcc -m64 -Wall -g hello.c -o hello-64
```

to compile `hello.c` into a 32 bits executable `hello-32` (resp. a 64 bits executable `hello-64`)

You could add some other options, eg `-mtune=native -O2`

As [Jonathan Leffler wisely answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958888/841108), the same program can be compiled for a 32 bits or for a 64 bits system. It is up to you to ensure that the behavior is sensible.

You probably want to use the C99 standard [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) header. With a recent (GCC 4.9 or better) compiler, you might want to code for [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) using `-std=c11` compiler flag.

Avoid casting pointers to or from integral types. If you absolutely need that, use `intptr_t` etc...

Comment: ty too basile, will try out

Answer (score 3):

In C you simply need a 64 bit compiler and a 64 bit platform to run the code on.

For the most part there will be little difference between your actual source code, but there are some platform differences to be aware of.  Different OS use different [64 bit data models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models); for example in Win64 a `long` remains 32 bit, while Solaris `long` becomes 64 bit.  If you have code that relies on long being 32 bit, you will need to modify that code - in such cases it would have always been safer to use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` in any case.

Solaris on SPARC64 all data types other than `short` and `char` become 64 bit, which may then require some care porting existing code.

[image: 64 bit data models]

Comment: is there a int64_t aswell? or, lets say a short32_t?

Comment: @DatLuckey: the `<stdint.h>` header defines types for fixed sizes like `int8_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint64_t` (always both signed and unsigned, assuming they are available), and some non-fixed sizes like `intmax_t` and `uintptr_t`.  There isn't a `short32_t` on any system I've ever heard of.

Comment: There is no `short32_t` - 32 bits is the explicit length - the term short in the name would be redundant.  It is not about specifying or redefining the length of `int` or a `short` - you cannot change that; but rather about specifying an *integer* representation of a specific bit length.  The names are simply type aliases for *built-in* data types. So for example on LLP64 `int32_t` may be an alias for either `int` or `long` as they are both 32bit, while on LP64 it is an alias for `int` only. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/ for details of types defined in `stdint.h`